# Who is the voice actress for the 'young' Nori-chan from the anime Kiznaiver?

Tags: voice-acting, kiznaiver

Unless I am mistaken, it seems as if Nori-chan from the anime Kiznaiver has two different voice actresses. One for the 'young' Nori-chan and one for the main part of the story.

**My question** -
Who is the voice actress for the 'young' Nori-chan?

[image: A picture of Nori-chan]

The young voice can be heard in

- season 1 episode 1 at the start of the episode
- and season 1 episode 10 at around the 21m:44s (timing includes opening song).

I'm sure I've heard this voice before, it is incrediby irritating.

Comment: If my answer helped your question, don't forget to mark it as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren't played by the same person.

> Who is the voice actress for the 'young' Nori-chan?

Teenage Sonozaki is played by YAMAMURA Hibiku, but child Sonozaki is played by 財前咲良 (probably read "ZAIZEN Sakura"). She's credited in episode 1 as "girl" (少女).

[image]

In episode 9, she's again credited, this time as "Sonozaki (child)" (園崎（幼少期）). Curiously, her name is spelled 財前咲来 this time. She has barely any internet presence, but judging from [this page](http://www.theatre.co.jp/school_fukuoka), I think the episode 9 spelling is correct. (The same spelling is used when she's credited in episode 10.)

[image]

> I'm sure I've heard this voice before, it is incrediby irritating.

As near as I can tell, this is her first role in anime, so you probably haven't heard her before.

It does appear that she [voiced young Cinderella in the Japanese dub](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%B3%E3%83%87%E3%83%AC%E3%83%A9_(2015%E5%B9%B4%E3%81%AE%E6%98%A0%E7%94%BB)#.E7.99.BB.E5.A0.B4.E4.BA.BA.E7.89.A9) of [Disney's 2015 *Cinderella*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinderella_(2015_Disney_film)), though, and I imagine she might've had some other minor gigs (commercial voiceovers, etc.) too.